# Why simple json request body in Postman is not working

Tags: postman

Can someone explain to me why this request is not working and showing me "invalid character" at colon!
[image]

Comment: Try removing the space before the colon

Comment: please add the body as string so that we can try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You have copied the json body from browser or other non standard text editor so the asci character for "," is not the actually one. it got resolved into something else . Just delete it and replace that comma and double quotes with correct correctors.

```
{
  "message":"hi",
  "tg_chat_id": "5"
}
```

Also in postman you can press ctrl+b to format and remove space , (that's not the reason for error though)

Answer (score 6):

In Headers tab must be checked

1. Content-Type
2. Content-Length

Comment: This worked for me. The API was saying the JSON wasn't correct, yet it 100% was. The Content-Length header was missing. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me. Content-Length header was missing in Postman

Answer (score -1):

The POST URL you are using might be wrongly written. 400 typically means you passed something invalid to the API. This error message tends to be pretty helpful when it comes to figuring out what is wrong.

Just try keeping a single Key Value pair in `Headers` like `Content-Type application/json`.

Body->raw->JSON selection looks okay.

JSON should be like this:

```
{
  "message":"hi",
  "tg_chat_id":"5"
}
```